# Realtek Ethernet problem in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet, realtek, lspci

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I am experiencing connectivity issue for ethernet. LAN port blinks while connecting LAN cable. But couldn't establish a connection.

`Additional Informations`

```
x@y:/sbin$ lspci | grep -i Ethernet
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev ff)


  $lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3
  01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
  RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev ff)
  DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
  Kernel driver in use: r8169
  Kernel modules: r8169

  $ ifconfig
    eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:b5:2f:2a:c5:4d  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

Comment: It is not possible since you have there `01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev ff)`. It is case sensitive. It is not `eth`.

Comment: @Pilot6 :  `lspci -knn` gave the above output in question, but I couldn't find any output shown onterminal for `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

Comment: How do you get the output running `lspci | grep -i Ethernet`?

Comment: @Pilot6 : `lspci | grep -i Ethernet` too didn't show anything, just ends the command

Comment: The first line in your question is the output of that command that is not empty. And why are you using some bluetooth Ethernet emulation?

Comment: I did dpkg -r r8168-dkms in between

Comment: `r8168` is not for that adapter. Did you reboot?

Comment: You should run `sudo modprobe r8169` since `r8168` disabled it.

Comment: Did `sudo modprobe r8169`,  still no output for `lspci | grep -i Ethernet`

Comment: It looks like the Ethernet adapter is disabled in BIOS or broken. Before you see it in `lspci` it makes no sense to fiddle with drivers.

Comment: I checked in BIOS for enable/disable option for Ethernet but couldn't find any. I am using HP 2000-2116tu. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If r8169 is not in my system, how to get it?

Comment: It is in the kernel. As I said until you see the adapter in `lspci`, everything else does not matter.

Comment: @Pilot6 Have changed the system battery, now getting the above output for the input you said.  
still connecting in ethernet port doesn't connect to lan. What to do?

Comment: You can try to install `r8168-dkms`. But I don't think it will work.